# creating a baseline on bigfix using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, api, automation

https://developer.bigfix.com/rest-api/api/baseline.html
https://gist.github.com/chriswahl/ad66652f8905b44b1e77

I have used these links for writing the code.
The task is to create a baseline using powershell. The task is defined in the xml. Using the rest api, I have to pass the xml to the TEM tool using powershell. I have tried it but the baseline is not created. Also there are no errors popping out. The links have instructions for the task in python. But, I have to do it powershell only.

We have the permissions to run scripts and also the admin access. There is no specific time to run the script. The version of server is 2012R2

```
$body = 
'''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BES xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BES.xsd">
<Baseline>
<Title>${baselineName}</Title>
<Description></Description>
<Relevance>true</Relevance>
<Category></Category>
<Source>Internal</Source>
<SourceID></SourceID>
<SourceReleaseDate>2015-12-21</SourceReleaseDate>
<SourceSeverity></SourceSeverity>
<CVENames></CVENames>
<SANSID></SANSID>
<MIMEField>
<Name>x-fixlet-modification-time</Name>
<Value>Mon, 21 Dec 2015 17:24:53 +0000</Value>
</MIMEField>
<Domain>BESC</Domain>
<BaselineComponentCollection>
<BaselineComponentGroup>
 <BaselineComponent Name="${Name}" IncludeInRelevance="true" SourceSiteURL="http://sync.bigfix.com/cgi-bin/bfgather/bessecurity" SourceID="${SourceID}" ActionName="Action1"><ActionScript></ActionScript><Relevance></Relevance></BaselineComponent>
</BaselineComponentGroup>
</BaselineComponentCollection>
</Baseline>
</BES>

'''

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dec124.lab:52311/api/baselines/{site type}/{site name}" -Method POST -Body $body
```

After executing this script, no new baselines are created on TEM. Also, there are no errors.

The baseline is created from an action or a computer group. The id of the computer group and the it's location are source id and source location.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It makes no difference whether you use Invoke-RestMethod in PowerShell or cURL in in Terminal. This is not really a PowerShell issue. If you use the correct URL, you get some kind of response. The URL in your code above returns 'Invoke-RestMethod: No such host is known.'

Comment: https://dec124.lab:52311/api/baselines/{site type}/{site name} . In this url, dec124.lab is the hostname of the server, 52311 is the default TEM port, site type and site name of the TEM tool.

Comment: What error do you get when running: Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dec124.lab:52311/api/baselines/{site type}/{site name}" -Method POST -Body $body

Comment: There is no error. But at the same time, the task is also not done. I am not sure where the mistake lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to add a parameter to the invoke-restmethod cmdlet.

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dec124.lab:52311/api/baselines/{site type}/{site name}" -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType "application/xml"
```

This change gives the expected result.